# Nginx server config: Access paged wihout php extention, and giving dedicated & seperate php folder

Tags: nginx

As the title says, Im looking for a configuration that makes PHP files accessible without their extension from a requested URL, and direct PHP access disallowed.  But also having separate folders for PHP scripts, and resources.  In this case folders in www root named "php" and "public" in respective order.  I am running nginx/1.10.3 on Ubuntu.

I have tried more than I can remember, nearly all listings on DuckDuckGo that I can find.  The problem seems to be with the 'if' block, as it does not rewrite the uri even when the file exists.  I have tried to instead include this rewrite in a separate location titled '@phpext', and included that in the try_files, but no luck.  Ive tested php-cgi itself, and its working fine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
    server_name potatoi-t.com www.potatoi-t.com;

    root /servers/www/;
    index index;

    location / {
        if (-f /php$uri.php) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /php$1.php last;
        }
        try_files /public$uri /public$uri/index =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        internal;
    }
}
```

I expect for the following url's to resolve to the following files:

`http://www.potatoi-t.com/`
    (through php-cgi) /servers/www/php/index.php

`http://www.potatoi-t.com/images/existingImage.php`
    /servers/www/public/images/existingImage.php

`http://www.potatoi-t.com/index.php`
    (returns 404)

`http://www.potatoi-t.com/nonExistantFile`
    (returns 404)

Any advice is highly appreciated!  Im self taught, and new to nginx config, so explanations if not a nu-sense, I am greatly thankful for.  Thankyou!

Comment: The `-f` operator expects a pathname and not a URI. Try: `if (-f $document_root/php$uri.php) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided works.  The `-f` operator needs a path, not a URI that is relative to the root directory.  Combining the URI with the `$document_root` variable makes a path to a possible valid location in the filesystem.

> The -f operator expects a pathname and not a URI. Try: `if (-f $document_root/php$uri.php) { ... }`